# Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-sdk

I can't find it anywhere nor can I find any article on how to install it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin
```

or look at page 103 in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=lwKACwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server.dll%20download&source=bl&ots=znR6glLFnb&sig=vv5ZfAVaS6KyjiDyBTftzfIDubM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7m7qTk8bMAhUBGz4KHdgTB-oQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server.dll%20download&f=false)

**Update:**
I just realize that you need `tfs` installed on your PC or grab it from `tfs server`.